# Different mlocate database for each user?

Tags: freebsd, locate

This may come across as a silly question because each file and directory on a system can and will have permissions to block an ordinary user from seeing various files- but for added security sake and a context too long to get into: Can mlocate have multiple databases for different groups of users? Or every user for that matter?

The goal is to limit knowledge or access to files that ordinary users shouldn't even know exist- but the root and sudo accounts should still be able to see everything in the system using a root mlocate db.

I've previously simply restricted read access to the mlocate database, but this is not an option on the current system. If there's a method to thread mlocate for multiple installations, I'd only require two and there's no storage constraints just as an FYI. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mlocate`, by default, only shows files that the user has access permission to.  At least on my CentOS 7 build:

For example:

```
% rpm -qf /usr/bin/locate
mlocate-0.26-8.el7.x86_64

% locate /root/.ssh

% sudo locate /root/.ssh
/root/.ssh
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
/root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This works because `locate` is setgid and the data file is locked down to that group:

```
% ls -l /usr/bin/locate              
-rwx--s--x 1 root slocate 40520 Apr 10  2018 /usr/bin/locate

% sudo ls -al /var/lib/mlocate
total 142820
drwxr-x---  2 root slocate      4096 Feb 23 03:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 45 root root         4096 Dec  6  2018 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root slocate 146233302 Feb 23 03:38 mlocate.db
```

And, indeed, a normal user can't even locate the db file :-)

```
% locate '/var/*mlocate*'       
/var/lib/mlocate

% sudo locate '/var/*mlocate*'
/var/lib/mlocate
/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.khYLWG
```

The setgid option may work on FreeBSD as well.

Comment: Oh awesome thanks Stephen, that's very clever, I had no idea!